# custom UITableViewCell exception

Tags: ios, uitableview

What can it be?
Failed to set (identifier) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key identifier.
On iOS 8 it works, but spamming in debugger, in prior versions it crash app.
All connections in interface builder i checked and reconnected.

My code cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as PostCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "post_like_active"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        cell.dislikeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "post_dislike_active"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

        var storageManager: PostStorageManager = PostStorageManager.sharedManager()
        var model: PostModel = storageManager.storageObjects()[indexPath.row] as PostModel

        cell.likeButton.selected = model.likeManager.likeState!.liked
        cell.dislikeButton.selected = model.likeManager.likeState!.disliked

        cell.textView.text = model.text
        cell.textView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: fontSize)!
        cell.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.contentInsetTop, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        cell.likeLabel.text = String(format: "%@", model.amountOfLikes)
        cell.dislikeLabel.text = String(format: "%@", model.amountOfDislikes)

        var date: NSDate = model.date

        cell.timeLabel.text = date.timeAgo()

        var tapRecog: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapOccure:")
        tapRecog.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecog)

        var isMan = model.isMan.boolValue

        cell.trollfaceImage.image = UIImage(named: String(format: "%@_%i", isMan ? "man" : "woman", model.experiance.integerValue))

        var manColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 86/255, blue: 115/255, alpha: 1)
        var womanColor = UIColor(red: 206/255, green: 68/255, blue: 96/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.ageLabel.textColor = isMan ? manColor : womanColor
        cell.ageLabel.text = String(format: "%i", model.age.integerValue)

        cell.textView.userInteractionEnabled = false

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: please post the code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: is it crashing on dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier line?

Comment: yes, it stops on exception breakpoint on this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all views in the cell, I think you put your identifier in the wrong place.